# Problems with tcolorbox and TikZ external

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-external

I am writing a book which will contain a lot of TikZ figures and tcolorboxes. To speed things up I want to use the TikZ external library. However, I have run into some problems that I would like to understand. Perhaps this is a bug? The problem is that even if I use `\tcbset{shield externalize}`, some keys for the tcolorbox seems to cause problems.

One minimal example I can give is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tcbset{shield externalize} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}     

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, attach boxed title to top left, title=Title]
    Hello
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

This gives errors that hint at problems with TikZ trying to externalize the title box. Removing either `\tikzexternalize` or `attach boxed title to top left` will make the problem go away.

I cannot find anything in the (otherwise very excellent) manual for tcolorbox about this being a problem. Can anyone explain what is going on here or is this perhaps a bug with `shield externalize`?

In this particular case, my workaround is using `\tikzexternalenable` and `\tikzexternaldisable` around each `tikzpicture`, however, I would very much like to avoid that. So, perhaps someone can also give me some alternative method to externalize tikz figures, e.g. using latexmk?

For completenes: I am using "pgf 2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)" and "tcolorbox 2018/12/07 version 4.15 text color boxes".

Comment: As a workaround you could disable externalization for the box explicitly: `\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, attach boxed title to top left, title=Title]
    Hello
\end{tcolorbox}
\tikzexternalenable`

Comment: Yes, that also works. However, that prevents any TikZ image inside of the box to not be externalized. But in the end, I think I will have to use the same number of enable/disable. I would very much prefer an automatic approach if possible.

Comment: Did you try with `external` tcolorbox library instead of `TikZ` externalization. It's more limited than `TikZ` one but, may be, it avoids your problems. It's documented in section 24 (v4.20 tcolorbox).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for the problem is that the boxed title is a `tcolorbox` itself, but with a higher layer number. For this higher layer, the global setting of `shield externalize` is reset to the default, i.e. to be `false`.

For almost all options this reset is useful (documented in section 4.16). But, I think, for `shield externalize` this is not true. Also, the documentation claims that `\tcbset{shield externalize}` in the preamble shields any `tcolorbox` inside the document.

The problem should vanish, if you replace `\tcbset{shield externalize}` by `\tcbsetforeverylayer{shield externalize}`, because this is applied to all boxed on all layers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
%\tcbset{shield externalize}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{shield externalize}% <--- interim solution before bug fix


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, attach boxed title to top left, title=Title]
    Test
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Since I cannot imagine a use case, where one does not want to apply this for all layers, I will change the implementation for the next version of `tcolorbox`. The future change will remove `shield externalize` from the `reset` operation. After that, `\tcbset{shield externalize}` will be adequate as claimed by the documentation.